# Яндекс карты с перемещнием позиции

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

```
<script type="text/javascript">
ymaps.ready(init);
var myMap;

function init(){     
    myMap = new ymaps.Map ("map", {
        center: [55.76, 37.64],
        zoom: 7,
    });
}
</script>
```

Для статического положения понятно. Допустим я получаю координаты и сохраняю их в переменных. Как перезагрузить местоположение, не перезагружая саму карту?

Comment: [по теме пример][1]


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/229452/yandex-maps-api-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=229563#229563

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос вам нужно переместить карту к новому местоположению
есть 2 варианта

```
 myMap.panTo(
    // Координаты нового центра карты
    [55.753, 37.609], {
        /* Опции перемещения:
           разрешить уменьшать и затем увеличивать зум
           карты при перемещении между точками 
        */
        flying: true
    }
)
```

или

```
 myMap.setCenter([40, 50], 3, {
    checkZoomRange: true
});
```